# Issue with kfold through the loo package for R through rstanarm

Tags: bayesian, predictive-models

I am comparing two models with 10 fold cv with each specified as:

```
stan_lm(form_b, prior = R2(0.5), data = models_rf) 
stan_glm(form_b, family = gaussian, prior_intercept = normal(0, 2, autoscale = FALSE), data = models_rf )
```

I get sensible coefficients for both models and no errors from stan. Diagnostics all look great, however when I run kfold with K = 10 I get

```
[[1]]

 10-fold cross-validation

           Estimate SE
elpd_kfold      NaN NA

[[2]]

10-fold cross-validation

           Estimate  SE
elpd_kfold    -44.1 3.1
```

Any ideas what I'm missing? There are no NAs in the dataframe, but I'm wondering if there is some underlying statistical error I am making.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was answered in Stan discussion forum http://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/kfold-returning-nan/1943